# Writing numbers with dashes below it

Tags: support, mathjax

I would like to know if we could write numbers as given in this maths [website](http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/20-combinatorics/05-combinations-01) with dashes below it.

Comment: Do you mean something like $\underline{8}\cdot\underline{7}$ `$\underline{8}\cdot\underline{7}$`?

Comment: @MartinSleziak:Yes absolutely that.

Comment: Sometimes these lines don't line up: $\underline{x}\cdot\underline{y}\cdot\underline{z}$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Write \underline{\mathstrut x}, and the underlines will line up:  $\underline{\mathstrut x}\cdot\underline{\mathstrut y}\cdot\underline{\mathstrut z}$.

Answer (score 1):

As [Martin Sleziak suggested in a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22315/writing-numbers-with-dashes-below-it#comment87573_22315), use `\underline{}` which will produce $$\underline{{\text{blahblah}}}.$$